# How to change name of project in android studio toolbar?

Tags: android-studio

I have successfully copied my project and named it something else and its working fine everything is good the only problem is that in the tool bar the name of the project is shown as directory.

[image]

Even though the project name changed to MyChat and all but at the top it show's old name then directory then the file name. how to change it so that it only shows current project name and file that is opened?

like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to - settings.gradle and change the name from here

[image]

Comment: Thank you. it worked. I will accept this answer after 8 min.